# How could I save Image from url into app?

Tags: iphone

I am developing iPhone application, and I want to store image which is loaded from url into application document folder, but i don't know how to do this.

any suggestion?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Apple's [URLCache](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/URLCache/index.html) sample.